# How do I create a bootable USB drive?

Tags: boot, usb, bios, formatting, zip

I have had a Matebook X Pro for about three weeks and I am running Ubuntu 18.10 on it. Recently I have restarted the computer following some installation guide and a problem occurred. The computer turns on, flashes the Huawei logo once, turns off, then two seconds later repeats this behaviour and this boot loop goes on forever. When I press f12 to bring up the boot menu and select the SSD it says boot failed (even though the computer does see the SSD as an available bootable drive).

I have searched some forums (mostly reddit) and found that the problem seems to be the outdated BIOS.

I have downloaded the updated BIOS zip file onto my USB flash drive to update BIOS, but my USB is not formatted as a bootable device.

What program do I have to use in order to make my USB bootable to update BIOS to a newer version from the BIOS menu using the zip file? (the computer doesn't boot up at all, not even until the Ubuntu loading screen)

Comment: How you install BIOS firmware should be documented by the OEM.  Why do you believe a firmware update is an appropriate solution to your problem?  The problem you describe won't be solved by a firmware update, your problem seems to have happened out of the blue, firmware issues would typically have always existed.

Comment: @Ramhound I have found a reddit thread where the person was having the same boot loop issue with the exact same computer, so i thought I will give it a try, although I'm always open to new suggestions. Could you please clarify what OEM stands for?

Comment: Huawei is the original equipment manufacturer (OEM) for your device.  The firmware on Huawei's website has instructions included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I have solved the issue and I really hope that anyone who has it can benefit from my answer.

All I had to do was to go into BIOS (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>) then disable secure boot that is enabled by default. Then it all booted up and none of my data was lost. Thank you to everyone who tried to help

Answer (score 1):

> I have downloaded the updated BIOS zip file onto my USB flash drive to update BIOS, but my USB is not formatted as a bootable device.

The files provided by Huawei is simply a Windows catalog file.  The process to update the firmware for your device cannot be started outside of Windows.

> What program do I have to use in order to make my USB bootable to update BIOS to a newer version from the BIOS menu using the zip file?

In order to update the firmware, you must boot into Windows, and follow the included instructions.  You install the firmware update, by installing the catalog file, Huawei has not provided the required files to install the firmware using another method.  **The firmware cannot be updated from within Linux.**

> I have searched some forums (mostly reddit) and found that the problem seems to be the outdated BIOS.

**Your problem will not be solved with a firmware upgrade.**  Based on the problem described, your inability to boot into an OS is simply due to an unidentified configuration change.

Comment: While I would love to submit a solution to your boot issue, there isn't enough information, to properly identify the issue or the cause of your current situation.  So I have answered, the original question, which addresses the main concern of how to perform a firmware update on the device.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was very insightful. I do not have windows anymore as I completely replaced it with Ubuntu. As for the problem itself, what details can I give you for you to help me identify the cause of the problem?